# blast.js animation with jquery ui color animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, animation

I'm using blast.js to animate two words, and jquery ui to be able to animate color. Everything I've tried hasn't worked.

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/kaqivirupe/edit?html,js,output)

CSS is irrelevant in the DEMO because there are no css rules for the color button.

```
var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);

$('.color_button').on('click', function(){
    var words = $('color_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'word',
        generateValueClass: true
    });
    words.each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
    color: newColor
    }, 500);
});
});
```

The goal is to get the colors of each word to change to a random color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add this jQuery color plugin to your project, as it appears to be missing from the DOM: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js (I had to copy & paste the entire script into JSbin, using `<script>` tags.)

Then change your code to look like this. The newColor has to be generated inside of the onClick for the button plus inside of the .each() function, which loops over the individual words. Then the "Color Text" button will randomly change text colors for each individual word.

Version 1:

```
$('.color_button').on('click', function(){
    var words = $('.color_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'word',
        generateValueClass: true
    });
    words.each(function(idx, obj){
      var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
      $(obj).animate({
        "color": newColor
      }, 500);
    });
});
```

Version 2 (see comments):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var words = $('.color_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'word',
        generateValueClass: true
    });
    words.each(function(idx, obj){
      var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
      $(obj).animate({
        "color": newColor
      });
    });
},500);
```

Version 3 (see comments - here is a sample jsfiddle for the [auto-timer](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/tcnusr6y/)):

```
var timer = null;
(function setColor() {
    var words = $('.color_body').blast({
        delimiter: 'word',
        generateValueClass: true
    });
    words.each(function(idx, obj){
      var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
      $(obj).animate({
        "color": newColor
      });
      if (!timer) {
          timer = setInterval(setColor,2000); // Loops continuously.
      }
    });
})(); // This function will Auto-Run 1x
```

Comment: Do you know how I would make this change colors continuously without the button needing to be pressed? Would I just need a setTimeout?

Comment: Try using setInterval as it will repeat on an infinite loop, until cleared. The  setTimeout function will only loop 1x & then stop. It takes extra code to put setTimeout into an infinite loop, whereas setInterval would work great for that! Simply replace the 1st & last lines in the answer code example with `setInterval(function(){` and `}, 500);`, respectively. Then take the 500ms timer out of the .animate function & it should work.

Comment: Never used interval, good to know. I'm going to bug you one more time and ask how I would set it up so that it sets the interval after it has changed color once. Otherwise it appears to do nothing on click for 2000 ms the way I have it set

Comment: I've added 2 more code examples for you to look at.